# Actualizar div automáticamente

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Tengo un `textarea` donde se van poniendo los mensajes que pone el **usuario1** y el **usuario2**, lo que quiero es que cada cierto tiempo, por ejemplo 5 segundos se actualice el `div` solamente.

Para ello he encontrado varios ejemplos donde usan el `load` pasándole un página a cargar.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
        $("#feedback-bg-info").load("url a cargar")
        .error(function() { alert("Error"); });
    }, 1000);
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });              
});
```

En esta parte `$("#feedback-bg-info").load("url a cargar")`, en el método `load`, lo que busco es que se actualice solo el `div` sin pasarle una ruta diferente.

Comment: Disculpa, se supone que el Div ya se actualiza, o quieres que se actualize otro div o el mismo?

Comment: @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales seria el mismo div, en vez de actualizar toda la pagina que sea solo ese div cada 5 segundos.

Comment: la url a cargar tiene que ser un endpoint distinto al que sirve la página principal. Uno que sólo devuelva el div.

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con *"actualizar"*? ¿Limpiar?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Para actualizar el div solamente , la funcion setInterval() que estas utilizando calza perfecto con lo que deseas ya que la misma llama a una funcion o evalúa una expresión en un intervalo de tiempo especifico expresado en mili segundos. Ahora replicando lo que tu planteas muestro la siguiente pagina:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


<div id="feedback-bg-info"><textarea></textarea></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
      var refreshId =  setInterval( function(){
    $('#feedback-bg-info').load('index.php');//actualizas el div
   }, 1000 );
});

</script>
</body>

</html>
```

con la expresion:

```
 $('#feedback-bg-info').load('index.php');
```

Solo estarías actualizando el div de tu pagina, ya que llamas al id con el cual lo definiste. En el load ingresa el enlace de tu pagina actual.

Te dejo un enlace de una pregunta similar [Aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15998853/refresh-a-div-with-php-data-every-10-seconds-using-jquery) Espero te Sirva!

Comment: gracias me sirvio tu respuesta. @Samuel Heredia

Answer (score 0):

Puedes realizar lo siguiente:

```
// Función de javascript para ejecutar repetidamente
window.setInterval(
    function(){
    // Sección de código para modificar el DIV
    // $("#miDiv").text(variable);

    // Ejemplo: Cada dos segundos se imprime la hora
    console.log(Date());
  }
  // Intervalo de tiempo
,2000);
```

Mas información: [FUNCIONES JAVASCRIPT – SETINTERVAL() CLEARINTERVAL() SETTIMEOUT()](https://www.pedroventura.com/javascript/funciones-javascript-setinterval-clearinterval-settimeout-2/)